# Regular expression that ignores certain characters

Tags: regular-expression

I need to find a regular expression, that ignores certain characters for usage in the bib2bib tool.
For example: I need to find any occurence of the word "muller". But also a string like
   ''Hello, my name is Michael M\"uller, how are you?''
or
  ''There is M\"{u}ller''

should be found.

Edit: I need this to work not only for "muller" but dynamically for every word.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use the `bib2bib` tool?

Comment: If none of the answers presented so far meet your needs, it might help if you gave a more thorough explanation and more comprehensive examples of what you want. For example, would you want to match "muLLer"? (If you want case-insensitive matching across the board, say so.) How about "Mull\"er"? If the search string is "rene", would you want to match "Ren\'e"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove things like `\"` and `\"{` and `}`, you will have to preprocess your input file with a tool like `sed` before feeding it into `bib2bib`.

Example:

```
 sed -e 's/\\"\{\|\\"\|\}//' input.bib > input.bib.preprocessed
```

Or to specifically convert things like `\"{u}` into `u`:

```
 sed -e 's/\\"{\(.\)}/\1/' -e 's/\\"//' input.bib > input.bib.preprocessed
```

Comment: But doesn't the preprocessing actually prohibit the match - as the characters which the asker wishes to match have actually been removed?

Comment: @mikeserv I thought he wanted to ignore the `\"` and so on to be able to match e.g. `muller` with `M\"uller`.

Comment: But how does it match it, though? I mean if you do : `printf %s\\n 'M\"uller"' | sed 's/[\"]//g' | grep -i muller` you don't match `M\"uller"` w/ `grep` but `Muller` - and that's what it prints. It doesn't print `M\"uller"`.

Answer (score 3):

A fully portable solution could look like:

```sh
n='
';printf %s\\n muller wright dummy >/tmp/patterns
tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]' </tmp/patterns |
paste '-d\n\n' - /tmp/patterns |
sed "N;s/./\\$n&/;:ul$n s/\(\n\)\(.\)\(.*\n\)\(.\)/\2\4\1\3/;tul"'
       s/\n//g;s/../[{}\\"]*[&]/g'
```

The output from that last `sed` looks like:

```sh
[{}\"]*[mM][{}\"]*[uU][{}\"]*[lL][{}\"]*[lL][{}\"]*[eE][{}\"]*[rR]
[{}\"]*[wW][{}\"]*[rR][{}\"]*[iI][{}\"]*[gG][{}\"]*[hH][{}\"]*[tT]
[{}\"]*[Dd][{}\"]*[uU][{}\"]*[Mm][{}\"]*[mM][{}\"]*[Yy]
```

It would depend on the contents of *patterns* being only alphanumeric characters. If *patterns* contained, for example, either of `[]` it would require further testing to ensure that the square brackets were placed correctly each within their respective bracket expressions.

In any case, based on the example in question:

```sh
[{}\"]*[mM][{}\"]*[uU][{}\"]*[lL][{}\"]*[lL][{}\"]*[eE][{}\"]*[rR]
```

...is a regexp that will match a line containing any of *`muller`* or *`Muller`* or *`M"ulL\\\{"er`*.

With GNU `sed` you can handle the case conversions within `sed` itself, so:

```sh
sed -E 's/([[:upper:]]?)([[:lower:]]?)/\1\L\1\2\U\2/g' patterns
```

...prints...

```sh
mMuUlLlLeErR
wWrRiIgGhHtT
DduUMmmMYy
```

...fully fleshed out, you can get the same behavior as the previous `tr|paste|sed` combination *(except that, this way, the aforementioned square-bracket problem is handled correctly)* with just GNU `sed` like:

```sh
sed -E '
    s/([[:lower:]]?)([[:upper:]]?)/\1\U\1\2\L\2/g
    s/[[:alpha:]]{2}|./[{}\\"]*[&]/g
' </tmp/patterns
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned in what way you have your data available. To remove lines containing the posted patterns you can use `grep`:

```
grep -v -E '(muller|M\\"uller|M\\"{u}ller)'
```

(Note that the `\` needs another escape.) To match the inverse, lines with the given patterns, omit the `-v`.

To define the regular expressions in a file use `grep`'s option `-f`, as in:

```
grep -v -E -f file-with-regexps
```

It expects one regexp per line in that file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this only works for muller. I need it to work dynamically.

The data is in a file which is parsed with another tool (bib2bib), which accepts regular expressions.

Comment: If you can't generalise from the suggestion please provide an example data file

Comment: @user133713 No, it works for the three words that you asked for.

Comment: @user133713 If that "bib2bib" tool has an own regexp parser you should better consult the documentation (or man page) of that tool. The solution provided uses standard Unix extended regexps.

Comment: @User133713 Could you clarify what the process is you are working on? Please edit your question...